# Problems with Using Exists Qualification Comparator on MechanicalTurk

Tags: mechanicalturk

Can't see my qualified HIT using a worker with that qualification.

HIT qualification in the sandbox uses 'Exists' comparator, e.g.

```
<HIT>
    <HITId>32K26U12DN1PNMK2MAJPEQNECILVDO</HITId>
    <HITTypeId>3WOK1A2U0I5SR1CN9O4HRI9RTQ71DZ</HITTypeId>
    <HITGroupId>319N3DB41A1IF8ZIEZVLOZ1ZDBUEPL</HITGroupId>
    <CreationTime>2015-02-12T16:55:49Z</CreationTime>
    <Title>Talk to a voice based information system Feb12D</Title>
    <Description>Feb12D has qualificatino</Description>
    <HITStatus>Assignable</HITStatus>
    <MaxAssignments>10</MaxAssignments>
    <Reward>
        <Amount>0.22</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
        <FormattedPrice>$0.22</FormattedPrice>
    </Reward>
    <AutoApprovalDelayInSeconds>864000</AutoApprovalDelayInSeconds>
    <Expiration>2015-02-22T16:55:49Z</Expiration>
    <AssignmentDurationInSeconds>1800</AssignmentDurationInSeconds>
    <QualificationRequirement>
        <QualificationTypeId>3VCRHAWCXM1RNIKBV31U03UE6YJWFW</QualificationTypeId>
        <Comparator>Exists</Comparator>
        <RequiredToPreview>0</RequiredToPreview>
    </QualificationRequirement>
    <HITReviewStatus>NotReviewed</HITReviewStatus>
    <NumberOfAssignmentsPending>0</NumberOfAssignmentsPending>
    <NumberOfAssignmentsAvailable>10</NumberOfAssignmentsAvailable>
    <NumberOfAssignmentsCompleted>0</NumberOfAssignmentsCompleted>
</HIT>
```

I assigned the qualification with a value of 100 to my sandbox worker (currently AKBFZAA9AUVUI)

However, the worker is unable to see the HIT.

Any suggestions on what might be wrong with the HIT?

PS [Cross posted](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=171543)

Edit:  The HIT above has since been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:  The problem is due to whitespace in the Qualification Type identifier.  Be sure to trim the whitespace from either end of the string containing the qualification identifier.